# How To: Displayed image file name different than actual filename on server

Tags: php, javascript, html, image, file

I would like to display an image but have the file name different than the actual file name on the server.

ex) The user would see `<img src="/img/photos/Awesome_Picture_By_John.jpg">` by looking at the source code

but the actual file name would be /img/photos/12b7dch2.jpg

any help is appreciated. Thx

Comment: Do you have an idea for how this relates to JavaScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done pretty easily. I think you could do something like this with mod_rewrite, turn the existing

```
/img/photos/Awesome_Picture_By_John.jpg
```

Into something like

```
/img.php?id=Awesome_Picture_By_John
```

and have img.php pull the real filename out of the database.

Here is a good [mod_rewrite tutorial](http://www.workingwith.me.uk/articles/scripting/mod_rewrite) to get you started.

Comment: how long will this linkage have to remain in the rewrite rules? You might create a symbolic link to 12b7dch2.jpg by the name of Awesome_Picture_By_John.jpg. is there a possibility of wanting to call several things Awesome_Picture_By_John.jpg?

Comment: The rewriting rule needs to be generalized, like: RewriteRule ^/img/photos/(.+)$ /serve_real_image_from_fancy_filename.php?fancy_filename=$1